# ChromeDriverと普通にブラウザで検索した結果が違う

Tags: python, chromedriver

ご存知でしたら、ご回答下さい。

PythonでChromeDriverを使用してAliexpressのスクレイピングを行おうとしました。
しかし、ChromeDriverと普通にブラウザで検索した結果が違います。
Aliexpressにはどちらもログインしていません。

[例リンク](https://ja.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20221104164955&isPremium=y&SearchText=%E9%81%8A%E6%88%AF%E7%8E%8B%E3%80%80%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88&spm=a2g0o.productlist.1000002.0)

リクエストヘッダーに違いはありませんでした。

何か原因をご存知ないでしょうか？

Comment: [シークレット モード](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=ja) での結果が普段と異なるなら, 閲覧内容が記憶されてるからかも

Answer (score 2):

自己解決しました。

Cookieに何か原因があったようです。
ブラウザのCookieを削除したらDriverと件数が合いました。